# Reject empty hash from hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I got this hash in params
`user_groups_attributes

```
=> {"0"=>{"name"=>"hello", "id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["201"]},
 "1"=>{"name"=>"hello2", "id"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["83"]},
 "2"=>
  {"name"=>"dddddddddd", "id"=>"5", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["256"]},
 "3"=>{"name"=>"", "id"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}`
```

and I need reject all with id = "". how can I do it?

Comment: Start by showing us the code you've written toward doing this. It's easier, and better, for us to correct your code, than to write code you then have to shoehorn into your program. As a starting point though, [`reject`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-reject) is your friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `nested_attributes` you can do this

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_groups, reject_if: lambda{|attr| attr[:id].blank?}
```

I know you did not specify Rails in the question or the tags but the question still seems Railsy to me.

Answer (score 2):

```
hash = {"0"=>{"name"=>"hello", "id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["201"]},
 "1"=>{"name"=>"hello2", "id"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["83"]},
 "2"=>
  {"name"=>"dddddddddd", "id"=>"5", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["256"]},
 "3"=>{"name"=>"", "id"=>"", "_destroy"=>"false"}}

hash.reject!{|a, b| b["id"].empty?}
#=> {"0"=>{"name"=>"hello", "id"=>"1", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["201"]}, "1"=>{"name"=>"hello2", "id"=>"2", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["83"]}, "2"=>{"name"=>"dddddddddd", "id"=>"5", "_destroy"=>"false", "user_ids"=>["256"]}}
```

Comment: Mary, since the values of `hash`'s keys are not used in Vimsha's calculation, the block variable `a` can be replaced by an underscore (as a placeholder), should you wish to draw attention to that fact: `hash.reject! { |_, b| b["id"].empty? }`.